# How can my Main() method be holding references to variables that have been disposed and are no longer used?

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

I'm working on fixing memory leaks in a large project, and so I've shrunk it down into one Main() method wherein a reference type object `Obj1` containing a reference to another reference type object `Obj2`. Then, I create another object of type `Obj1` which contains a reference to the same `Obj2` object. Both of the objects are in their own using blocks, like so:

```
using (dynamic obj1_a = new Obj1(args)) 
{
    do some actions...
    using (dynamic obj1_b = new Obj1(args))
    {
        do some more actions...
        //Memory Snapshot 1 taken here
    }
}
GC.Collect();
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizer();
GC.Collect();
//Memory Snapshot 2 taken here
```

Somehow, when I take the 2 snapshots at the points commented above and compare them, .NET Memory Profiler indicates that even though the two objects `obj1_a` and `obj1_b` have been disposed, they haven't been GC'ed. When I examine the reference graphs, I see that the memory profiler says that both objects are referenced by my Main() method itself. I've gone through the whole code of the Main() method (it's not very complex, just creating, slightly modifying and then testing for garbage-collection) to see if there is a variable reference remaining to these two objects but there are none. How is it still possible that my Main() method could be holding these objects in memory? It's important that they get garbage collected (or at least are able to get GC'ed) because they contain references to many more reference and value types and the program becomes quite a memory drain without it.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you'd provide a [mcve]. Note that `obj1_a` and `obj1_b` aren't objects - they're variables. Do you have other variables whose values refer to the same objects that those variables refer to? Also note that calling `Dispose` does not in itself matter to GC at all.

Comment: I would imagine that using `dynamic` also complicates things, as there is a lot of IL code generated behind the scene.

Comment: @Dirk I can't imagine how that would possibly affect the object's lifetime.

Comment: Show the `Dispose` method of `Obj1`, do you also dispose your `Obj2`? You say both share the same reference which means that it's `static`? Can you also show the declaration and initialization of the `Obj2` field/property?

Comment: what are args in this case and how are obj1 and obj2 initialize with args?

Comment: it's a little tough to show specific code as there's some privacy concerns, but I'll try to answer as best I can - I'm sure the objects that `obj1_a` and `obj1_b` refer to aren't referenced by anything else. I know that Dispose doesn't matter to the GC but the Dispose method calls other methods that should remove all references to the object, and according to my memory profiler, it does so successfully. The only reference left says "Main() method".
"Args" is just a placeholder I left @deezg

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> even though the two objects obj1_a and obj1_b have been disposed, they haven't been GC'ed

Your statement presupposes that there is a connection between an object being disposed and it being deallocated by the garbage collector. Make sure you fully understand the following statement: **disposing an object has no effect whatsoever on whether it is eligible to be collected**. From the GC's perspective, `Dispose` is just a method. You might as well say "even though I called `ToString` on an object, it still hasn't been GC'd".  What does `ToString` have to do with the GC? Nothing. What does `Dispose` have to do with the GC? **Nothing whatsoever**.

Now, this slightly overstates the case. A finalizable object should implement IDisposable, and its Dispose should call SuppressFinalization. That has an effect on the garbage collector because *finalizable objects always live at least one collection longer than they otherwise would because the finalization queue is a root*. But here the effect is not due directly to `Dispose`; it is simply a convention that disposers suppress finalization. It is the suppression which has an effect on the GC behaviour.

> How is it still possible that my Main() method could be holding these objects in memory?

An object is collected by the GC when the GC determines that there is no *living root* containing a direct or indirect reference to the object.

A local variable in an active method is a living root.

The runtime is permitted to, entirely at its discretion and for any reason whatsoever, to both (1) determine that a local is never read again and treat it as dead *early*, and (2) keep a local alive *longer* even when control has passed beyond the local variable declaration space of that variable.

Even though your `obj1_a` and `obj1_b` are out of scope by the time the GC runs, the runtime is entirely permitted to pretend that they were declared at the top scope of `Main`, and is permitted to keep them alive until `Main` completes, which is *after* the GC runs.

> It's important that they get garbage collected (or at least are able to get GC'ed) because they contain references to many more reference and value types and the program becomes quite a memory drain without it.

If you *require* fine-grained control over lifetimes of objects then *languages which have automatic memory deallocation do not meet your requirements*.

Comment: Even though the application may not have need for deterministic handling of garbage collection, it would be advantageous if you can write code where this guarantee exists. Even if it is only throw-away code that is written in a test console app to run from a memory profiler.
For instance, will refactoring into a method solve this or do you risk the compiler expanding the method inline? Are there attributes you can use?

Comment: @Tormod: **If you require fine-grained control over lifetimes of objects then languages which have automatic memory deallocation do not meet your requirements**.