# Why doesn't garbage collector in net core 2.0 free all memory

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-2.0

I'm running simple code on net core 2.0 and after garbage collection my program still consume 140 MB of ram. Does anybody know why and how I can reduce it? I also have side question. Are there any differences between garbage collection in console application and web application?

```
var rand = new Random();

var list = new List<Test>();

for(int i = 0; i < 10_000_000; i++)
{
    list.Add( new Test {
        Id  = i,
        Number = rand.NextDouble(),
        Number1 = rand.NextDouble(),
        Number2 = rand.NextDouble(),
        Number3 = rand.NextDouble(),
        Number4 = rand.NextDouble(),
        Number5 = rand.NextDouble(),
        Number6 = rand.NextDouble(),
        Number7 = rand.NextDouble(),
        Number8 = rand.NextDouble(),

    });
}

Console.WriteLine("End of generation");
Console.ReadLine();

for(int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    list[i] = null;
}

list = null;

GC.Collect(1);

GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

GC.Collect(2);

GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

GC.Collect(3);

GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Did you test this on .NET framework to claim it's a .NET Core "issue"?

Comment: I tried on .NET Framework and it goes back to 10 MB in release and debug mode.  Looks like memory problem is present only in debug mode in .net core. After runing code on core 2.0 in release mode it worked ok.

Comment: @user9159375 - You should probably report this to Microsoft. It sounds like a bug, and since it doesn't happen in release mode it probably won't be reported by anyone else.

Comment: How do you measure the RAM consumption?  Even if GC frees the memory for the process, CLR may not be quick to return it to the OS, or the OS may not mark it as free immediately.

Comment: @Nick there are diagnostics tools in Visual Studio

Comment: Possibly related even though it is not .net core: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44635530/261050

Comment: Run the code that produces a list in a separate method, see if that changes anything. Debug extends the lifetime for some objects to the end of the method to allow you to inspect variables. If a temporary variable is created at any point in the method it doesn't matter that you change the variable you created to null, there might still be a lingering reference back there. If you move this code to a separate method and call it, before you start collecting garbage, such temporary variables will no longer exist and might change the outcome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tested your code, and it is indeed as you described. I took a snapshot and looked at the objects, and there is still a `List<Test>` in memory.

If you run it in release mode, all memory is freed as expected.

So I would guess, it is a <strike>bug</strike> behavior in debug mode.

EDIT: [Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen made an interesting comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48301031/why-doesnt-garbage-collector-in-net-core-2-0-free-all-memory#comment83590041_48301031):

> Debug extends the lifetime for some objects to the end of the method to allow you to inspect variables.

I tested it and if you put code that produces the list in a separate method, all memory is freed.

Comment: I really wouldn't call it a bug, it's almost certainly how it's intended to work.

Comment: Great point with the "separate method". This worked for me too.

Answer (score 1):

If this reference type (the list) is local to this method JIT compiler can actually allocate it on the stack instead of the heap and with `Console.Readline();` stack is never deallocated but I don't really know how you test this.

About the difference between GC, yes I think we had issues once in our company and we actually found out that GC for console applications is different than the one for web application.  As far as I remember GC in web app was ran in server mode, don't remember the mode of GC for console apps tho.

More on GC modes here : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/seteplia/2017/01/05/understanding-different-gc-modes-with-concurrency-visualizer/